# Disable package refreshing when starting emacs

Tags: spacemacs, init-file, package-repositories

I have bad internet connection. Starting spacemacs takes a long time because of the "refreshing package archive melpa or gnu or others...".  or "installing package: ...".

When i put the computer on plane mode and start emacs this is not a problem since the actions are not executed. Nevertheless, when I forget to do so and the internet connection is bad emacs enters in a sort of "crashing state" trying to refresh or install the packages.

Is there a way to stop packages from automatically refreshing and installing on emacs start up?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You have a misconfigured .emacs file. Check if you have something like
‘package-refresh-contents’ in your init.

Comment: I agree, check your emacs startup file. Emacs does not refresh or install packages by default.

Comment: I don't find anything like that

Comment: I Tried this and it seems faster when starting:    dotspacemacs-elpa-timeout 0